# Need help understaning how I can store and access variables from class to class

Tags: java, android, class, bundle

If I create a spinner inside of onPostExecute() in an AsyncTask can I store its value in that class and then retrieve it from another class. Or How can I store it in Bundle?

```
 private class CallEventList extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return readEventJSONFeed("service call", null);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        try {
        ...
        //....create the spinner....
                event_spinner.setAdapter(eAdapter);

                event_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(..... // create the listener
                //removed code for easy reading......

                    String selected_event = event_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    //Here I want to store the value for use in another class.


                    }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the string `selected_event` static and not a method variable but a class one.
But i wouldnt recommend that as easy as it may look.

Another approach is to use a call back, create a constructor for `CallEventList` similar to this

```
CallBackNamedHowYouLike mCallback;
public CallEventList(CallBackNamedHowYouLike callback){
    this.mCallback = callback;
}
```

Then in your post execute...

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    try {
    ...
    //....create the spinner....
            event_spinner.setAdapter(eAdapter);

            event_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(..... // create the listener
            //removed code for easy reading......

                String selected_event = event_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                //Here I want to store the value for use in another class.
                callback.aMethodWhereYouUseSelectedEvent(selected_event);

                }
    }
```

Assuming you called this asynctask from the class you want to use that String then i will invent that class

```
public class TheClassFromWhereYouNeedTheString implements CallBackNamedHowYouLike {
...//a lot of your code is here

@Override
public void aMethodWhereYouUseSelectedEvent(String selected_event){
this.yourString = selected_event;
}

}
```

And finally the interface will be this...

```
public interface CallBackNamedHowYouLike{
void aMethodWhereYouUseSelectedEvent(String selected_event);
}
```

Comment: what would you recommend?

Comment: Sorry, I am a bit slow with Java.. What is aMethodWhereYouUseSelectedEvent():? in the other class do I callback.aMethodWhereYouUseSElectedEvent().toString()?

Comment: Ok. This really spells it all out. Give me a bit to digest and experiment.

Comment: No, i mean the whole idea is to have your asynctask have an interface between itself and the activity (i assume the class where you need this string is an activity) This way you can construct the asynctask sending your activity as a parameter, then assigning that value to a local interface (a bit of polymorphism there) that way you can "talk" to the activity from the asynctask

Comment: It is a lot but is worth the while, it comes very handy with a little practice. I am not saying is the best way, there are more complex design patterns but this is fast and easy